# How to get data in hexadecimal format using Perl and the Google::ProtocolBuffers module

Tags: perl, hex, decode, protoc

It is necessary to read data in hex format

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Google::ProtocolBuffers;
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);

Google::ProtocolBuffers->parse("
    message TestMessage {
      required double tag1 = 1;
    }
",
    {create_accessors => 1 }
);

my $enc = TestMessage->encode({
    tag1 => 0, 
});

write_file('data.bin', { binmode => ':raw' } , $enc);

my $dec = read_file('data.bin', { binmode => ':raw' });

my $protoc = TestMessage->decode($dec);

print $protoc->tag1;
```

I tried it with this module, it reads any number as float64.
And when I try to use the protoc command, everything is as it should.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>protoc --decode_raw < data.bin
1: 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: Small suggestion: instead of `open` + `binmode`, use the 3-argument form of `open`: `open my $fh, '>:raw', 'data.bin' or die "...";`

Comment: Yes, it was just an example, I came up with it on the fly..

Comment: Still waiting for a better example (a value other than zero)

Comment: Tip: I recommend File::Slurper over File::Slurp

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely unclear, but I'm guessing you are asking for the hex representation of the bytes of an IEEE double-precision floating point number in big-endian byte order.

```perl
my $n = 123.456;
```

First, get those bytes.

```perl
# my $packed = "\x40\x5E\xDD\x2F\x1A\x9F\xBE\x77";
my $packed = pack( "d>", $n );
```

Notes:

- This only works on a machine that uses IEEE floating point numbers, but that's basically every machine these days.
- Use `f` instead of `d` for single-precision.
- Use `<` instead of `>` for little-endian byte order.

Then, get the hex representation of those bytes.

```perl
# my $hex = "405edd2f1a9fbe77";
my $hex = unpack( "H*", $packed );
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I formulated the question incorrectly. I need an analogue of --raw_decode for perl.

Comment: I looked at the source, and Google::ProtocolBuffers doesn't provide a way to avoid decoding "primitives". But you could re-encode it as I showed.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it produce the correct value for zero. Maybe if you provided a better example?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Solved the problem using the "protoc" binary in my perl script.